# Can't install new theme or features in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Hi I'm trying to change my Theme or install new feature and VS Code throws an error:

> Unable to write into settings. Please open User Settings to correct
>   errors/warnings in the file and try again.

How can I fix this?
[image: This is the problem]

Comment: which OS? Linux, Mac, Windows?

Comment: this is in Windows

Comment: can You upload settings.json file to somewhere, we want to check it?

Comment: The problem is 
I can't find them!

Comment: go to VSCode folder and check if there is settings.json, otherwise seems like UAC prevents to save file to same directory by security reasons.

Comment: No I didn't find the file

Comment: ok, try to run as administrator

Comment: Are you running the latest version of vscode? v1.15.  They recently added a gear icon in the lower left, click on it and select settings.

Comment: I can go to settings from the VScode, but no from folder